# Flutter Navigator 2.0: access RouterDelegate state from outside

Tags: flutter, flutter-state

I am using Navigator 2.0 and I have my state stored inside the `RouterDelegate` so that I can have the `currentConfiguration` react to state changes.

This is like all examples I saw. For example:

```
 BookRoutePath get currentConfiguration {
    return _selectedBook == null
        ? BookRoutePath.home()
        : BookRoutePath.details(books.indexOf(_selectedBook));
  }
```

How can I set the property `_selectedBook` from some widget down the tree?
I solved that in the rest of the app using `Provider` and passing a `ChangeNotifier`.

However I am not sure how to do that with `RouterDelegate`.

Is there a way I can access its state?

Or is there a way I can store the state in another class and still have `currentConfiguration` update every time `_selectedBook` changes?

Comment: I think [this](https://github.com/yeasin50/Flutter-project-Helper/blob/master/navigator2/withSengment1_detailsScreen.dart) might help you to solve the case